# Python: screenshot em loop salvando por cima

Tags: python

Por qual motivo o código abaixo salva o arquivo um por cima do outro?

Eu desejo que a cada *screenshot* gere um arquivo separado dentro da pasta especificada.

```
import datetime
import pyautogui
import time

#armazena o nome do arquivo no formato dinâmico de ano-mês-dia_hora minuto_segundo, assim: "2018-05-09_224510.png"
nomeArquivo = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%M-%d_%H%M%S'+'.png')

#loop para ficar tirando foto da tela de 10 em 10 segudos.
while True:
    foto = pyautogui.screenshot() #faz a foto
    foto.save('C://Users//WJRS//' + nomeArquivo) #salva na pasta indicada.
    time.sleep(10) #atraso de 10 segundos entre uma screenshot e outra.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque o nome do arquivo só é definido uma vez, quando o código é iniciado. Assim, todos as capturas de tela terão o mesmo nome e, consequentemente, sobrescreverá o arquivo anterior. Para evitar isso, você precisa atualizar o nome do arquivo conforme o horário colocando a definição do mesmo dentro do laço:

```
while True:
    nomeArquivo = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%M-%d_%H%M%S'+'.png')
    foto = pyautogui.screenshot()
    foto.save('C://Users//WJRS//' + nomeArquivo)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Poxa vida! Verdade! Muito obrigado Anderson Carlos. Eu confesso que eu estava esgotado ontem, após 8 horas de trabalho e mais 3 horas de estudos eu já não estava bem... Muito obrigado!